# Fish shell wildcard returns different output

Tags: fish

I'm trying to create a fish function with named argument contains a wildcard `*`. But the output between the function I made and the plain command are different.

Here's my function:

```
function ls-wildcard -a arg
    ls $arg
end
```

and here's the result when I tried to execute it

```
$ ls-wildcard path/*.foo
bar1.foo
```

The output shows only 1 file when there should be 2 of them. But the plain `ls` works like a charm.

```
$ ls path/*.foo
bar1.foo   bar2.foo
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:
After I tried some different expressions, the behavior of the function seems to terminate itself after the first matched. any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard is expanded *before* the function is run.

Your function uses a named argument, which is *one* argument.

So it is equivalent to this:

```
function ls-wildcard
   ls $argv[1]
end

ls-wildcard path/*.foo
# runs `ls-wildcard` like
ls-wildcard path/bar1.foo path/bar2.foo
```

and then your function throws away the second argument.

The simplest fix is to just use `$argv`:

```
function ls-wildcard
    ls $argv
end
```

which will forward all arguments to `ls`.

Comment: ah, I get the point. Thanks! But, the real function I'm gonna make requires 2 named arguments with the wildcard is at the second argument. lets say `function x -a arg1 arg2`. and the usage will be `x foo path/*bar`. so it means the `$argv` I'm gonna use is from `$argv[2]` to `$argv[n]`. could you give me an example for this?

Comment: Named arguments only work for one element. You can just use a slice like `$argv[2..-1]`.

Comment: yep, `$argv[2..]` do the trick! thanks!